# Meteor: Insert field into MongoDB only if a value exists

Tags: javascript, mongodb, validation, meteor, file-upload

I have a form where a coverImage and an attachment is optional. However, currently the user has to fill out all the forms. If not, meteor prints the warning:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: imageIdVar is not defined

I understand where this error message comes from.

So, how can I make the fields optional while inserting the document into the collection?

My template helpers:

```
Template.adminNewsEvents.events({
    'change #coverImage': function(evt, temp) {
    /* FS.Utility.eachFile(event, function(file) {
      Images.insert(file, function (err, fileObj) {
        // Inserted new doc with ID fileObj._id, and kicked off the data upload using HTTP
        if (err) throw err;
      });
    }); */

        var image = event.target.files[0];

        // Insert the image into the database
        // getting the image ID for use in the course object
        var imageObject = Images.insert(image);

        // The image id is stored in the image object
        var imageId = imageObject._id

        // Create a reactive var to be used when the course is added
        imageIdVar = new ReactiveVar(imageId);

    },
    'change #attachment': function(evt, temp) {
    /* FS.Utility.eachFile(event, function(file) {
      Images.insert(file, function (err, fileObj) {
        // Inserted new doc with ID fileObj._id, and kicked off the data upload using HTTP
        if (err) throw err;
      });
    }); */

        var attachment = event.target.files[0];

        // Insert the image into the database
        // getting the image ID for use in the course object
        var attachmentObject = Attachments.insert(attachment);

        // The image id is stored in the image object
        var attachmentId = attachmentObject._id

        // Create a reactive var to be used when the course is added
        attachmentIdVar = new ReactiveVar(attachmentId);

    },
    'submit form': function (evt, temp) {
        evt.preventDefault();
        NewsEvents.insert({
            title: $('#title').val(),
            description: $('#description').val(),
            type: $('input[name=netype]:checked').val(),
            coverImageId: imageIdVar.get(),
            attachmentId: attachmentIdVar.get(),
            createdAt: new Date ()
        });

        $('#title').val('');
        $('#description').val('');
        $("input:radio").removeAttr("checked");

        console.log("done");
    }
});
```

I thought about using an if-statement to check if the var are truthy but this seems cumbersome.

I'm using the following packages:

- cfs:standard-packages
- cfs:filesystem
- reactive-var
- dburles:collection-helpers

Any help highly appreciated.

Comment: try `console.log` in submit form whether your `imageIdVar` is actually getting passed or not.

Comment: @KawsarAhmed: whenever someone uploads a file, it is passed. and the insertion works flawlessly. but uploading an image is optional. so if a user doesn't upload an image the whole document won't get inserted :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you have to do is install [underscoreJS](https://atmospherejs.com/meteor/underscore) in your meteor project. Then before adding into the database check like this

```
_.isUndefined(imageIdVar);
```

this returns boolean whether your `imageIdVar`  and `attachmentIdVar` has some data or not. So if you get false, you'll skip image field `coverImageId` and `attachmentIdVar` in the `insert` method. As `MongDB` is Schemaless, you won't have problem inserting without these fields.

**a better approach**

```
var temp ={};
temp.title = $('#title').val();
// and for other variables also
if(!_.inUndefined(imageIdVar.get())) {
    temp.coverImageId = imageIdVar.get()
}
// you'll do also for attachment ID. then you'll insert the temp variable in the insert method
NewsEvents.insert(temp);
```

Comment: So it means, I have to build 4 different scenarios? if both are defined, I do as shown in my question. Then, I need three other insert functions: If none of the two is defined (1), or if just one of the two is defined (2) + (3).  Hm ... isn't there any "$exists" for inserting new entries?

Comment: yes you can do that. or think about a better solution. and `$exists` operator works for your db query, not for inserting values

Comment: I can't find a better solution. neither via google nor when I think about it. I know ```$exists``` is query-only. that's why I wondered if there's sth like ```$exists``` for inserting values.

Comment: I just tried your approach. looks great but I still get the exact same error/behaviour. inserting only works when the two optional fields are selected. even using _.isUndefined(imageIdVar.get()) doesn't return any boolean but rather "Uncaught ReferenceError: imageIdVar is not defined"

Comment: would you please do your work in `meteorpad` so that i can take a look when i get free time.

Comment: I ended up with a solution which is a mix of your and mine (s. my own answer). I marked yours as the solution :) 
Thx for your offer, though. You might be interested in my brand new question, though http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35116329/meteor-how-to-style-useraccounts ;)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Faysal Ahmed, I came up with a solution. You have to set the **ReactiveVar to false** at the beginning:

```
imageIdVar = new ReactiveVar(false);
attachmentIdVar = new ReactiveVar(false);

Template.adminNewsEvents.events({
    'change #coverImage': function(evt, temp) {
        var image = event.target.files[0];
        var imageObject = Images.insert(image);
        var imageId = imageObject._id

        if (imageId) {
            imageIdVar = new ReactiveVar(imageId);
        }
    },
    'change #attachment': function(evt, temp) {
        var attachment = event.target.files[0];
        var attachmentObject = Attachments.insert(attachment);
        var attachmentId = attachmentObject._id

        if (attachmentId) {
            attachmentIdVar = new ReactiveVar(attachmentId);
        }   
    },
    'submit form': function (evt, temp) {
        evt.preventDefault();

        var temp = {};
        temp.title = $('#title').val();
        temp.description = $('#description').val();
        temp.type = $('input[name=netype]:checked').val();
        temp.createdAt = new Date ();

        if (imageIdVar.get()) {
            temp.coverImageId = imageIdVar.get();
        }

        if (attachmentIdVar.get()) {
            temp.attachmentId = attachmentIdVar.get();
        }

        NewsEvents.insert(temp);
    }
});
```