# Meteor: how to style useraccounts

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, meteor, user-accounts

I'm using [meteor-useraccounts](https://github.com/meteor-useraccounts/core/blob/master/Guide.md) for handling user accounts - including `useraccounts:bootstrap`. My [boilerplate](https://github.com/meteor-useraccounts/boilerplates/tree/master/bootstrap-iron-router) is straight from the repo.

My issue:
I don't understand were to put my own HTML/CSS.

My config.js:

```
// Options
AccountsTemplates.configure({
    defaultLayout: 'emptyLayout',
    showForgotPasswordLink: true,
    overrideLoginErrors: true,
    enablePasswordChange: true,

    showLabels: false,
    showPlaceholders: true,

    negativeValidation: true,
    positiveValidation: true,
    negativeFeedback: true,
    positiveFeedback: true,
});

AccountsTemplates.addFields([
    {
        _id: 'firstName',
        type: 'text',
        placeholder: "First Name",
        required: true,
        re: /^[^\d]{2,}$/i,
        errStr: "Please enter your first name.",
    },
    {
        _id: 'surName',
        type: 'text',
        placeholder: "Sur Name",
        required: true,
        re: /^[^\d]{2,}$/i,
        errStr: "Please enter your first name.",
    },
    {
        _id: 'institution',
        type: 'text',
        placeholder: "Institution/Company",
        required: true,
        re: /^[^\d]{2,}$/i,
        errStr: "Please enter the institution or company you work for.",
    },
    {
        _id: 'position',
        type: 'text',
        placeholder: "Position",
        required: true,
        re: /^[^\d]{2,}$/i,
        errStr: "Please enter the your position in the institution/company.",
    },
]);
```

I read in the documents you should replace the original template with your own, that's what I did with `Template.myAtForm.replaces("atForm");` and the following template:

```
<template name="myAtForm">
  {{#unless hide}}
    <div class="at-form">
      {{#if showTitle}}
        {{> atTitle}}
      {{/if}}
      {{#if showError}}
        {{> atError}}
      {{/if}}
      {{#if showResult}}
        {{> atResult}}
      {{/if}}
      {{#if showOauthServices}}
        {{> atOauth}}
      {{/if}}
      {{#if showServicesSeparator}}
        {{> atSep}}
      {{/if}}
      {{#if showPwdForm}}
        {{> atPwdForm}}
      {{/if}}
      {{#if showTermsLink}}
        {{> atTermsLink}}
      {{/if}}
      {{#if showSignInLink}}
        {{> atSigninLink}}
      {{/if}}
      {{#if showSignUpLink}}
        {{> atSignupLink}}
      {{/if}}
    </div> <!-- end main div -->
  {{/unless}}
</template>
```

This is the given wireframe:
[image]

For example, where do I have to add the bootstrap classes so I have two input fields in a row (but NOT in every row as seen in the WF)? Or, how can I style my own upload button (there isn't even a `type:file` as far as I know)?

Event with the`useraccounts:unstyled` package, I don't understand where to put the HTML/CSS.

Any help really appreciated.

Comment: Build your templates and then call `Accounts.createUser` or `Accounts.loginWith<service>` manually.. (don't need useraccounts:*)

Comment: @webdeb: I thought about it, but useraccounts already does a great job and handles a lot of other stuff. if i just could add html/css in some way ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer: *Better write your own templates*

I am sure `useraccounts` is doing it's stuff very well. But it is targeting on simpler UIs. I guess the most of the apps are happy with it.

However, you can style all the fields with CSS. There are classes added to your fields templates (_id field). Take a look at the **generated** html and at the sources of `useraccounts:unstyled` package. Then you get a clear idea how its rendering algorithm is working.

But as you mentioned in your original post, there are no file fields for example. It would mean you have to add the templates by your self, and also manage the files upload logic/validation.

Comment: alright. thank you very much. :)
so i should just write my own UI but still use `useraccounts`, right?

Comment: write you own ui and handle it with the Meteor Accounts API